# How to filter playableStreams fields?

Tags: linkedin-api

I would like to filter fields returned via the `~:playableStreams` decorator (cf. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/digital-media-asset).

Is it possible? I tried but didn't succeed.

Also I can't find any documentation about the `~:` syntax. What doesn't it mean?

Best regards.